# Can't filter tests with includeTestsMatching

Tags: gradle, kotlin, junit5

I have a gradle project all written in Kotlin.

While removing the deprecated junit gradle plugin I am unable to filter tests since I am getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'the-project'.
> Could not find method includeTestsMatching() for arguments [*MyClassPostfix] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.filter.DefaultTestFilter.
```

I am using Gradle 4.8, Kotlin 1.2.51, Junit5 5.2.0, and junit-platform-launcher 1.2.0.

Relevant excerpt from build.gradle:

```
test {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching '*MyClassPostfix'
    }
    useJUnitPlatform()

    dependsOn 'cleanTest'

    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

Example of test class

```
internal class TestClassMyClassPostfix
{
    @Test
    fun foo()
    {
        assertEquals(0, 0)
    }    
}
```

Comment: Strange indeed since https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/d4133a7e85046ed2c6f677739043487f38a83898/subprojects/testing-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/filter/DefaultTestFilter.java seems to show that the method exists. All I can think of is a Groovy compiler inconsistency. Have you tried using brackets around the pattern argument?

Comment: What happens if you use the "old school" filtering support (i.e., `include(['**/*MyClassPostfix.class'])` directly inside the `test` task) instead of `filter.includeTestsMatching`?

Comment: @SamBrannen It works. I didn't know about this sintax, I was using the one from the gradle plugin of Junit5. Why this one works but gradle's native don't?

Comment: @johanneslink Using parenthesis it works. e.g. `includeTestsMatching('*MyClassPostfix')`, is it a gradle bug?

Comment: OK. Great: both variants work. So it was just a Kotlin syntax issue, nothing more.

Comment: @SamBrannen Do you mean Kotlin syntax in the source files or in Gradle? Because I am using Groovy and not Kotlin Script (kts). Could you please elaborate? Thank you

Comment: Sorry. I momentarily confused Kotlin and Groovy, thinking you were using Kotlin for the build scripts as well.

Comment: In Spring's test suite, I use `includeTestsMatching "org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.*"` inside `test.filter`, and that works (the last time I checked). So perhaps it's an issue with Groovy/Gradle. Might be best to ask on the [Gradle Forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/).